# Copying a file based on last modified date in batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy

Suppose my server generate a file at 1.30 and till 2.30 it will write in that same  file only and 2.31 it will create another file so if i run this batch file at 2.40 to get the data from 1.30 to 2.30 i need the file which is generated 1.30 not the 2.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

set enabledelayedexpansion
set /A counter=0

for /f %%f in ('dir /b /o:-d ^| find ^"file-mask^"') do (
set /A counter=!counter!+1
    if !counter! EQU 2 (
        copy %%f file2 /Y
        goto :endloop
    )
)
:endloop
endlocal
```

This will copy the second "last created" file.You can change the location where it will be copied and file mask.Check also robocopy and forfiles commands .Especialy robocopy.